# Makefile - Link static libraries to a dynamic library

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, static-libraries, dynamic-library

Assume I have this hierarchy of folders:

```
main
  dir1
    file1.cpp/h
    file2.cpp/h
    makefile
  dir2
    file3.cpp/h
    makefile
  makefile
```

Now, every inner makefile compiles the files to object files and creates a static library (*.a)

I want to build a shared object (dynamic library) from those static libraries (let's call them **libdir1.a, libdir2.a**)

I tried this rule on the makefile, but I accepted this error:

```
CC = g++

LDFLAGS = -shared
TARGET = libprog.so

$(TARGET): file1.o file2.o file3.o
         $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ -Wl,-whole-archive -ldir1 -ldir2 -Wl,-no-whole-archive

(compiler output)
    libdir2.a: member libdir2.a(file1.h) in archive is not an object
```

I don't know if the error derives from wrong building of the archive or because of a wrong target rule of the makefile.

Every archive was built with this rule:

```
$(TARGET): [list_of_obj_files_that_were_created_on_this_dir]
    ar -r -o $@ $^
```

Comment: You seem to have put a header file in your archive. Don't do that.

Comment: What is your `[list_of_obj_files]` ?

Comment: @Mat - as you see from the rule of the archive creating, only .o files are included in the archive

Comment: @水飲み鳥 - I edited the list, see there

Comment: The tools normally don't lie (though sometimes there are bugs). If they say you have an .h file in your archive, chances are it's true. Time for a close inspection of your archive creation commands. `[list_of_obj_files_that_were_created_on_this_dir]` is your interpretation of what is being done. What are the facts, i.e. the actual unedited commands?

Comment: Additionally, try removing and rebuilding the archives. If you have accidentally pushed an .h file into one, it will stick. `ar r` doesn't build the entire archive from scratch, it only replaces or adds specified members.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I accidentally included "h" file into the archive. It was because I used a variable to store the object file, but I didn't put the data on it well, so I thought that the variable includes only .o files, but in fact it had .h files too.